# inconsistency in unpacking a tuple of list(s)

Tags: python

Below is what I tested on IPython. The result of `print(*(a,a))` is what I expected but not `print(*(a))`. I though `print(*(a))` would give `[1,2]`. The background is that I have some function taking a list as an argument and this "unexpected" unpacking behavior caused errors of mismatch in argument numbers. I can work around it by using `([a])` as shown by the last print command. However, I think this inconsistent unpacking behavior is very unpythonic. Can someone explain it? Thanks.

---

```
In [82]: a=[1,2]                                                                                                                                                      

In [83]: print(*(a))                                                                                                                                                  
1 2

In [84]: print(*(a,a))                                                                                                                                                
[1, 2] [1, 2]

In [85]: print (*([a]))                                                                                                                                               
[1, 2]
```

Comment: `(a)` is not a tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print(*(a))` is actually the same as `print(*a)`.

Tuples of exactly one value need to be expressed with a single comma after the value, so the correct syntax would be:

```
print(*(a,))
```

This is [well-documented](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

> A special problem is the construction of tuples containing 0 or 1 items: the syntax has some extra quirks to accommodate these. Empty tuples are constructed by an empty pair of parentheses; **a tuple with one item is constructed by following a value with a comma** (it is not sufficient to enclose a single value in parentheses). Ugly, but effective.

---

I'd assume the reason behind this is that `(` and `)` are used to enclose *expressions*. For instance, consider the following:

```
x = (2 + 4)
```

What should be the value of `x` in this case? Logically, the intuitive (and actual) response is `6`, not a tuple. So why would `(a)` be any different?

`(a)` would simply yield ... `a`. The same way that `(2 + 4)` yields `2 + 4`.

In order to still be able to create a tuple of one element, the use of comma is enforced to distinguish between these cases and prevent any ambiguity.